# How to start Multi agent in jade using CMD?

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

hello every one i'm new in jade and i have a little question,
but first i have a 2 classes or let's say 2 agent : AgentA and AgentB .
when the AgentA start, he goes to wait state (because i'm working with FSMBehaviour).
Any way the AgentA sleep tell an event or message comes from the AgentB,
but the problem here is when the AgentB start , he will send a message to AgentA and then he will go to the waiting state also (waiting a replay from AgentA)
,so basically the problem here when i type this command in CMD to start the both of agents,

if the agent B start first , the code will not work ,
because the agent A here did not receive the message from agent B , so he is going to wait , and same thing for agent B here because he is going to wait tell agent A replay on his message

also if the agent A start first , the code may or may not work.
sometimes it works normal , and other times not.

basically i stuck in the message of 'en attente de l agent B'

this is the cmd command

> java jade.Boot -gui agentA:AgentA agentB:AgentB

i don't know where is the problem .
so how can i run more then one agent using cmd command
and also how can i tell the agent A to start before agent b in cmd command if this is possible
thank you

this is the code of AgentA

```
public class AgentA extends Agent {

protected void setup(){

  System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("----------------agent A----------------");
  System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

  FSMBehaviour agentA_beh= new FSMBehaviour();
  agentA_beh.registerFirstState(new attendreAgentB(), "attendreAgentB");
  agentA_beh.registerState(new envoiChiffre(), "envoiChiffre");
  agentA_beh.registerLastState(new fin(), "fin");
  agentA_beh.registerDefaultTransition("attendreAgentB", "envoiChiffre");
  agentA_beh.registerTransition("envoiChiffre", "attendreAgentB",0);
  agentA_beh.registerTransition("envoiChiffre", "fin", 1);//}
private class attendreAgentB extends OneShotBehaviour{

      @Override
      public void action() {

      System.out.println("en attente de l agent B");
      block();
      }
    }

/*****************************************************************/
private class envoiChiffre extends OneShotBehaviour{
  int valeurRetour = 0;
  @Override
  public void action() {

  ACLMessage messageRecu = receive();
  if (messageRecu.getContent().equalsIgnoreCase("pret") ) valeurRetour=0;
  else  valeurRetour=1;

  int chiffre = (int)(Math.random()*10);
  System.out.println("envoi de la valeur "+ chiffre);
  ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
  message.addReceiver(messageRecu.getSender());
  message.setContent(chiffre+"");  
  send(message);
  }      

  public int onEnd(){
  return valeurRetour;   
  }  
}
/*****************************************************************/
private class fin extends OneShotBehaviour{

  @Override
  public void action() {
  System.out.println("arret de l'agent A");
  myAgent.doDelete();  
  }  
}}
```

and this is the AgentB code

```
public class AgentB extends Agent {

  int somme = 0;
  boolean stop = false;
  protected void setup(){
    System.out.println("----------------agent B----------------");
    FSMBehaviour agentB_beh= new FSMBehaviour();

    agentB_beh.registerFirstState(new attendrechiffre(), "attendrechiffre");
    agentB_beh.registerState(new afficher(), "afficher");
    agentB_beh.registerState(new fin(), "fin");

    agentB_beh.registerTransition("attendrechiffre", "afficher",0);
    agentB_beh.registerTransition("attendrechiffre", "fin",1);
    agentB_beh.registerDefaultTransition("afficher", "attendrechiffre");

    addBehaviour(agentB_beh);

  }
  private class attendrechiffre extends OneShotBehaviour{

    int valeurRetour = 0;

    public void action() {
    ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
    message.addReceiver(new AID("AgentA", AID.ISLOCALNAME));  

      if(!stop){
        message.setContent("pret");
        send(message);
        valeurRetour=0;
        block();
      }else{
        message.setContent("arret");
        send(message);
        valeurRetour=1;  
      }    
    }
  public int onEnd(){
    return valeurRetour;
  }  
  }
  /**********************************************************************/
  private class afficher extends OneShotBehaviour{  
        @Override
        public void action() {
          ACLMessage messageRecu = receive();
          somme+= Integer.parseInt(messageRecu.getContent());
          System.out.println("message recu= "+ messageRecu.getContent());
          System.out.println("la somme actuelle = "+somme);
          if (somme > 50) stop = true;
        }  
      }
      /**********************************************************************/
      private class fin extends OneShotBehaviour{
        @Override
        public void action() {
          System.out.println("fin de l'agent B");
          myAgent.doDelete();
        }  
      }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Jade in many years, but if I am not mistaken, you should be able to check the directory facilitator if AgentA is present before sending a message. All agents should register with the DF upon joining, so other agents can check/search for them when sending messages. This is actually a rather well known problem with distributed systems in general.
Here's some examples: https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer5.html

Comment: i'll check it thank you

Comment: Were you able to move forward with this?

Comment: Post an answer if you think it can be helpful to others.

Comment: when i solve the problem i will post it , thanks men